# How to change background image with static css and maintain it?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question about background image change in MVC.

I have a main css for the website, multiple webpages within the website and i have a webpage within the user profile to change the background image of the website.

I have set up 4 pictures on a row with  function. I also have typed in a javascript prior to the images div, e.g in the top of

My problem is that when i run the page. the images wont change background when i click on the images. Thus I can change the background by image click if i go to inspect element and turn of background-image of my "Site.css" ( my main webpage css, ill throw in a gyazo here: http://gyazo.com/169070689792884090f1d9a9c9b96158).

Seems like the Site.css is static or something. Bootstrap is used on the website, also a masterpage is created, could that be a missing point from my pov.

also, how would I save the image to remain background on all pages afterwards?`

here is my cshtml code for image backgrounds:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Javascript - Change Background";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ButtonChangeBackground.css">

</head>
<body>

    <script language="JavaScript">

        var backImage = new Array(); 

        backImage[0] = "/Content/img/Wood_floor_by_gnrbishop.jpg";
        backImage[1] = "/Content/img/blue_wave_of_water-wide.jpg";
        backImage[2] = "/Content/img/Falling-asleep-forest.jpg";
        backImage[3] = "/Content/img/lava.jpg";

        function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
            if (document.body) {
                document.body.background = backImage[whichImage];
            }
        }

    </script>
    <div id="choosebg">
        <button onclick="javascript: changeBGImage(0);"><img id="wood" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" src="~/Content/img/Wood_floor_by_gnrbishop.jpg" alt="" /></button>
        <button onclick="javascript: changeBGImage(1);"><img id="water" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" src="~/Content/img/blue_wave_of_water-wide.jpg" alt="" /></button>
        <button onclick="javascript: changeBGImage(2);"><img id="forest" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" src="~/Content/img/Falling-asleep-forest.jpg" alt="" /></button>
        <button onclick="javascript: changeBGImage(3);"><img id="lava" style="width: 100px; height: 80px;" src="~/Content/img/lava.jpg" alt="" /></button>

    </div>
   <p> <div class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-2 "> @Html.ActionLink("Back to Profile", "Details") </div>

    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
...
function changeBGImage(whichImage) {
  if (document.body) {
     document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + backImage[whichImage] + ')';
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Its those little things in life. u know. engaging hand to face contact. Thank you G Ravinder! btw can't upvote because of low rep, sorry!

Comment: Btw G Ravinder, got any clue on how to switch main background-image for all pages with the new backImage?

Comment: for this you can use cookies to store the current image id or name
and then read from cookie each time the page loads and set the backImage to the page